# loading .csv file in R?

Tags: r, csv

I'm loading a csv file into R from the `Quandl` database.
the file is comma delimited and the data looks as follows:

```
quandl code,name
WIKI/ACT,"Actavis, Inc."
WIKI/ADM,"Archer-Daniels-Midland Company"
WIKI/AEE,"Ameren Corporation"
...
...
```

i use the following code to load the data:

```
US.Stocks <-read.table(file=ABC,header=FALSE,sep=",")
```

however, i get the following error:

```
Error in read.table(data.frame(file = ABC, header = FALSE,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection
```

Can someone pls help me with what im doing wrong? suspect ive not classified some parameter in the read.csv command?

thanks
Tom

Comment: Perhaps `(file="filename.txt",..)`

Comment: the file is a downloaded from the Quandl API as a csv file?

Comment: No idea, never used it before.  what is `ABC`?

Comment: Thanks for helping David. ABC is a csv file with the data as shown in the main part of the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

```
read.csv(file = yourFilePath, header = TRUE)
```

but I think the problem is in your file path, maybe you are missing file extension and remember to wrap your file path in double qoutes ( "yourfilepath" )

**UPDATE:**

`read.csv` is just wrappers around `read.table` with some default parameters

```
function (file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", 
    fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...) {
     read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
        dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
}
```

Comment: the full code looks as follows: StockData.Path <- "E:/data/WIKI_tickers2.csv"
US.Stocks <-read.table(file=StockData.Path,header=FALSE,sep=",")

Comment: i think it somehow seems not to recognise the comma before the names in colons?

Comment: use this instead: 
`StockData.Path <- "E:/data/WIKI_tickers2.csv"`  
`US.Stocks <- read.csv(file = StockData.Path, header = TRUE)`

Comment: There is no need to have `header=TRUE`, it is already the default value in `read.csv`. Plus, I managed to read the example file given in the question, (with @HPT's code), so the problem is definitely not in the data, at least not in the data you gave us.

Comment: thanks Vincent, I tried this, but the problem is that it does not then split the data along the ",". it seems to keep the data in one vector and create a second column(vector) in the dataframe with NA values?

Comment: can you upload your csv file and give us the link? @NMRQL

Comment: i managed to find the problem, thanks HP. it seems to be something taht Microsoft Excel does to the file if you open it. if however i download the file straight from its source ( https://s3.amazonaws.com/quandl-static-content/Ticker+CSV%27s/WIKI_tickers.csv) without having opened it in Excel to look at the data and resaved as csv, then it works aboslutely fine. however, if i do open the file first and save as a Csv, then read.csv works, but it seems to ifgnore the comma delimination? read.table, does not work now?